# Scheduled Event - InitiationHandler

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am working through the IRS demo, and trying to create a schedulable state / flow.

Has this TODO been done? I also can't find the `FixingSessionInitiationHandler` within the IRS-demo directory. Nor a generic `InitiationHandler` in corda directory in general.

```
TODO: Replace [FixingSession] and [FixingSessionInitiationHandler] with generic session initiation logic once it exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This TODO has been removed. Thanks for the heads up.